# Customizing Routes in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

When executed Search Controller - Index

```
public ActionResult Index(string parm1, string parm2)
```

Currently URL shows `/Search/Index?parm1=aa&parm2=bb`

I want to show /Search/aa/bb

I changed the mapRoute to:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchList",
            url: "Search/{action}/{parm1}/{parm2}",
            defaults: new
            {
                Controller = "Search",
                action = "Index",
                parm1= UrlParameter.Optional,
                parm2= UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

what am I missing?

Comment: do you have any other MapRoute before this one?

Comment: no, I have one after

Comment: how do you generate the URL?

Comment: If you want to have `/Search/aa/bb` work, you will need to remove the `{action}` in the route url like this: `url: "Search/{parm1}/{parm2}"`

Comment: @tweray works if I change the url manually to /Search/aa/bb but when it redirects to the url from code it still shows the querystrings. I am using: using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get)) to redirect to Index action. Do I need to change that to something else?

Comment: In this case, there's no out of the box solution for changing the form action url on client side from what I know. You may have to write your own javascript to make the url changing as you change the input on client side. It's only several lines of js but I'd ask if that's a option for you first.

Comment: @tweray why it works if entered manually and not from the code? what do you mean changing the form action url? I thought this is what MVC Route for to change the url formats? sorry for asking so much I am just new to MVC Routes.

Comment: Explaining can be slightly long that may not fit comment area, I will try to keep it short. Basically what `Html.BeginForm` do is only generate html `<form action="URL from route" method="GET/POST">`. And this only happen once on server side, on client side it will become pure html. i.e. on client side, it doesn't know what is route or how to regenerate that action url, which means you will have to use javascript to work it out yourself whenever user change search term on client side.

Comment: @tweray thanks for the explanation. Can you point me to link or sample on how to change the url in javascript? I tried by removing the Html.BeginForm and replacing with on button click and generating a url.action link but its not working i dont think I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's just a straight forward approach to make url change with search term. This is not out of the box and it won't have any exact binding to your route table, if you changed your route, then you have to manually fix it in the javascript. Also you may need to do some null/empty check when generating the url.

```js
$("input.search_term").change(function (e){
    
    //Get search terms and build new url
    var parm1 = $("input.search_term[name='parm1']").val();
    var parm2 = $("input.search_term[name='parm2']").val();
    var newUrl = "/search/"+ parm1 + "/" + parm2;
    
    //Change the link url, can do same thing on a form action url as well
    $("a.search_link").attr("href",newUrl);
  
    //For showing the text below, not necessary
    $("b.t_link").html(newUrl);
  
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search_term" name="parm1" value="aa" />
<input type="text" class="search_term" name="parm2" value="bb" />

<a class="search_link" href="/search/aa/bb">Search</a>

<!--not necessary-->
<br />
<span>URL of the link will be: <b class="t_link"></b></span>

<!--I assume you use jquery, let me know if you don't-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the example. A question you set default values in html code href="/search/aa/bb" do I need to set to something for default? also can I do similar with input type="submit"? or it only works with a href?

Comment: @Ben no you don't have set anything as default and leave them empty. But as I said you will need to deal with null/empty check while generating the url. It can work the same way in form submit, you just change the `action` or the form stead of the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchList",
            url: "Search/{parm1}/{parm2}",
            defaults: new
            {
                Controller = "Search",
                action = "Index",
                parm1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                parm2 = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```